# How to change my label value with 2 preentered .get?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, integer

Hope you are doing well!
I would write a code for my medical things and so on, but suddenly I faced a problem I have never faced before. Basically, it should be like 2+2=4 but variable_1-variable_2 instead. I have tried many different things like na=int(ion.get()) but nothing worked.

Problem:unsupported operand type -: "str"-"str"

I understand what it is but I have no idea how to fix that.
I would appreciate if you could take a look at my code below:
Thank you!

```
window=tk.Tk()
window.title="Calc"
label1=tk.Label(text="Enter Na")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2=tk.Label(text="Enter K")
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)


#here comes the first variable(int)
ion1=tk.Entry()
ion1.grid(row=0, column=1)
na=ion1.get()


#here is the second variable(int)
ion2=tk.Entry()
ion2.grid(row=1,column=1)
k=ion2.get()

label3=tk.Label(text="Your result is")
label3.grid(row=2,column=0)


#this is the value I want to modify
label_value=tk.Label(text="0")
label_value.grid(row=2, column=1)

#this is the function to modify the value above(label_value)
def calculate():
    global na
    global k
    global label_value
#here comes the problem:
    label_value.config(text=int(label_value["text"]+f"{na-k}"))

button=tk.Button(command=calculate, text="Apply")
button.grid(row=3, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

I tried:
na=int(ion1.get())
in function I tried int(label_value(text=na-k))
I have also tried to assign na and k to new list and then substitute the na from above to value from the list
and many many more things.

Answer (score 1):

You call `ion1.get()` and `ion2.get()` immediately after you create your `Entry` widgets, therefore they cannot have any value yet, only an empty string, and you cannot subtract an empty string from another, or convert it. Call the `.get()` functions from within `calculate()` and get rid of your global variables (theyre unneccessary, all relevant objects already exist and can be used at the point the function is defined). Updated function looks like this:

```
def calculate():
    subtracted_value = int(ion1.get()) - int(ion2.get())
    label_value.config(text=f"{subtracted_value}")
```